# How to divide duplicate rows in excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007

Say I have:

```
 ==============
|  a           |
|   a          |
|    a         |
|     a        |
|  b           |
|   b          |
|    b         |
|     b        |
|      b       |
|       b      |
|        b     |
|         b    |
|  c           |
|   c          |
|    c         |
|     c        |
 ==============
```

As you can see there are "a"x4 and "c"x4 but there are "b"x8. So what I basically want is to remove those extra "b"x4 duplicates so that I get:

```
 ==============
|  a           |
|   a          |
|    a         |
|     a        |
|  b           |
|   b          |
|    b         |
|     b        |
|  c           |
|   c          |
|    c         |
|     c        |
 ==============
```

Or How do I remove all duplicates so that I get:

```
|   a          |
|   b          |
|   c          |
```

FYI: My excel sheet is huge and the example of "b"x8 could be in random places

Comment: Can't you just [remove those rows](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/insert-or-delete-cells-rows-and-columns-6f40e6e4-85af-45e0-b39d-65dd504a3246)?

Comment: @LeonardoAlvesMachado its over 5000 rows in random order, I cant be certain in my eye mistake, see my update for new solution that might be ez

Comment: I see... How about using [a vba code for that](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/815-excel-remove-rows-based-on-cell-value.html#vba)? Have you tried?

Comment: @LeonardoAlvesMachado as I said I could have "d"(s) and in random location, so I cant  go  to that location and select "d" and then "e" and etc.

Comment: @Wajid, check I've posted a solution !

Comment: If the question is accurately described, you don't need to find rows.  Just delete columns to the right of the 4th position.

Comment: You've accepted an answer, but it doesn't seem consistent with what you described in the question.  Per the question and your comments above, there will never be duplicates within a column.  If the question accurately states the problem, you could reach the desired result by using a filter on the first column and hiding empty cells.  Then copy the result and paste it where you want, which would look like your final picture.

Comment: Also, if your objective is a list of unique values, what's the purpose of most of your question, which concerns limiting duplicates to a total of four?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

in the ribbon, Data >>> Remove Duplicates to remove Dups in the column

Comment: in that case it would remove the entire "b", so won't have "b" anymore but I want to keep just 1

Comment: @Wajid, have you tried?  it should keep only one "b" (one "a"  and so on)

Answer (score 0):

[image]

*Write this array formula in **cell G3**, finish with **Ctrl+Shift+Enter** and fill down.*

```
{=INDIRECT(TEXT(MIN(IF(($A$2:$F$16<>"")*(COUNTIF($G$2:G2,$A$2:$F$16)=0),ROW($2:$16)*100+COLUMN($A:$F),7^8)),"R0C00"),)&""}
```

You get the list of unique items.

**Note,** *adjust cell references in formula as needed.*

Answer (score 0):

Copy all data in a column and use remove duplicates, after removal only unique values will be left in that column.